# How to use the "6" char code in overloading insertion function on Scilab?

Tags: scilab

In the Help Documentation of Scilab 6.0.2, I can read the following instruction on the **Overloading** entry, regarding the last operation code "iext" showed in this entry's table:

> "The 6 char code may be used for some complex insertion algorithm like x.b(2) = 33 where b field is not defined in the structure x. The insertion is automatically decomposed into temp = x.b; temp(2) = 33; x.b = temp. The 6 char code is used for the first step of this algorithm. The 6 overloading function is very similar to the e's one."

But I can't find a complete example on how to use this "char 6 code" to overload a function. I'm trying to use it, without success. Does anyone have an example on how to do this?

Comment: Why do you need this kind of complicated overloading ? What is your user defined data type ?

Comment: I was trying to make a table with numerical data and for each column I 'd like to add some "metadata" that could be changed by insertion of structure type, like: `Matrix(j).type = "year"` where `j` is the number of the column, `type` is the name of the structure field and `"year"` is the value of the "column metadata". The matrix could also be accessed by regular notation `Matrix(i,j)`. I think I figure out how to do this and will post the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code bellow creates a normal "mlist" as a example. Which needs overloading functions

```
A = rand(5,3)
names = ["colA" "colB" "colC"]
units = ["ft"   "in"     "lb"]
M = mlist(["Mlog" "names" "units" names],names,units,A(:,1),A(:,2),A(:,3))
```

Following are the overload functions:

```
//define display
function %Mlog_p(M)
    n = size(M.names,"*")
    formatStr = strcat(repmat("%10s   ",1,n)) + "\n"
    formatNum = strcat(repmat("%0.10f   ",1,n)) + "\n"
    mprintf(formatStr,M.names)
    mprintf(formatStr,M.units)
    disp([M(M.names(1)),M(M.names(2)),M(M.names(3))])
end

//define extraction operation
function [Mat]=%Mlog_e(varargin)
    M    = varargin($)
    cols = [1:size(M.names,"*")] // This will also work
    cols = cols(varargin($-1))   // when varargin($-1) = 1:1:$
    Mat = []
    if length(varargin)==3 then
        for i = M.names(cols)
            Mat = [Mat M(i)(varargin(1))]
        end     
    else
        for i=1:size(M.names(cols),"*")
            Mat(i).name = M.names(cols(i))
            Mat(i).unit = M.units(cols(i))
            Mat(i).data  = M(:,cols(i))
        end
    end
endfunction

//define insertion operations (a regular matrix into a Mlog matrix)
function ML=%s_i_Mlog(i,j,V,M)
    names = M.names
    units = M.units
    A = M(:,:) // uses function above 
    A(i,j) = V
    ML = mlist(["Mlog" "names" "units" names],names,units,A(:,1),A(:,2),A(:,3))
endfunction

//insertion operation with structures (the subject of the question)
function temp = %Mlog_6(j,M)
    temp = M(j) // uses function %Mlog_e
endfunction

function M = %st_i_Mlog(j,st,M)
    A = M(:,:) // uses function %Mlog_e
    M.names(j) = st.name // uses function above
    M.units(j) = st.unit // uses function above
    A(:,j)     = st.data // uses function above  
    names = M.names
    units = M.units    
    M = mlist(["Mlog" "names" "units" names],names,units,A(:,1),A(:,2),A(:,3))
endfunction
```

The first overload (displays mlist) will show the matrix in the form of the following table:

```
--> M
 M  = 

      colA         colB         colC   
        ft           in           lb   

   0.4720517   0.6719395   0.5628382
   0.0623731   0.1360619   0.5531093
   0.0854401   0.2119744   0.0768984
   0.0134564   0.4015942   0.5360758
   0.3543002   0.4036219   0.0900212
```

The next overloads (extraction and insertion) Will allow the table to be access as a simple matrix `M(i,j)`.

The extraction function Will also allow M to be access by **column**, which returns a structure, for instance:

```
--> M(2)
 ans  =

   name: "colB"
   unit: "in"
   data: [5x1 constant]
```

The last two functions are the overloads mentioned in the question. They allow the column metadata to be changed in a structure form.

```
--> M(2).name = "length"
 M  = 

      colA       length         colC   
        ft           in           lb   

   0.4720517   0.6719395   0.5628382
   0.0623731   0.1360619   0.5531093
   0.0854401   0.2119744   0.0768984
   0.0134564   0.4015942   0.5360758
   0.3543002   0.4036219   0.0900212
```

Comment: good job. Keep up the nice work. Help other Scilab users here on SO. There are many [unanswered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scilab?sort=MostVotes&filters=NoAnswers&edited=true).